# How to make OpenAPI pick dependency from existing classes

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I have a definition in my YAML file, defined as below :

```
EQOptionPriceRequest:
    title: EQOptionPriceRequest
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/PriceRequest'
      - type: object
        properties:
          valuationDate:
            type: string
            format: date
          trade:
            $ref: '#/definitions/TradeDO'
          marketData:
            $ref: '#/definitions/EquityOptionMarketDataDO'
          config:
            $ref: '#/definitions/EquityOptionConfigurationDO'
        title: EQOptionPriceRequest
```

Classes `EquityOptionMarketDataDO` and `EquityOptionConfigurationDO` are already present in a jar file but when i generate Java stubs, using open-api generator plugin, it doesn't pickup those dependencies and instead generates a code thinking those files are in same package.

Can someone please advise on how to make open-api generator pick existing classes which generating stubs.

Comment: YAML cannot pick a dependency from classes. The only time dependency is mentioned in the YAML spec is in relation to parsing using parametrized BNF. Classes are only used once as well in the form of character classes (those forming digits, word, uri). This is something the OpenAPI generator does and it just happens to use [tag:yaml] (and [tag:character], [tag:file], [tag:utf], [tag:file-io], [tag:parsing], etc.)

Comment: @Anthon : Thanks. So as i understand YAML files only knows the files mentioned in spec and nothing outside it. Is that correct ?

Comment: YAML only knows about few special constructs in documents: anchors (starting with `&`) and aliases (starting with `*`), tags ( starting with  `!`), apart from its basic sequences and mappings. Other intepretation of scalars is done by a program, normally after it is parsed&loaded using a YAML parser. There are also programs, that first generate YAML from a template and then parse&load the resulting YAML.

Comment: You probably need the [`--import-mapping`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/wiki/Customizing-client-code-generation) option.

Comment: @Helen "import-mapping" is exactly what i was looking for, it solved my issue. If you can put it as an answer then i will accept it.